# React TypeScript BigCalendar Custom Toolbarbar Passing props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, react-big-calendar

I am having difficulties adding a custom toolbar to react big calendar. I am coding this in typescript but I am having difficulties passing props in my custom toolbar component that my parent class won't accept.
I know it's about the toolbar props that is causing the error but how it should be implemented compared to normal react is what sets me off course.

CustomToolbar.tsx

```
export interface ICustomToolbarProps {
      toolbar: ToolbarProps;  
}


const CustomToolbar = ({toolbar}: ICustomToolbarProps)  => {

    const goToBack = () => {
        toolbar.date.setMonth(toolbar.date.getMonth() - 1);
        toolbar.onNavigate('PREV');    }

    const goToNext = () => {
        toolbar.date.setMonth(toolbar.date.getMonth() + 1);
        toolbar.onNavigate('NEXT');
        };

    return (
        <div className='rbc-toolbar'>
            <PrimaryButton onClick={goToBack} style={{marginRight: "5px"}} text='Previous'/>
            <DefaultButton onClick={goToNext} style={{marginRight: "5px"}} text='Next' />
            <DatePicker />
        </div>
    )
}

export default CustomToolbar
```

MyCalendar.tsx

```
moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Paris')
const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment)


const meetingRooms: IMeetingRoom[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Stort mødelokale",
        color: "orange"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Lille mødelokale",
        color: "darkgreen"
    }
]


const events: IEvent[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Store mødelokale",
        allDay: false,
        start: new Date(2022, 10, 3, 7, 30),
        end: new Date(2022, 10, 3, 8, 20),
        locationId: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Lille mødelokale",
        start: new Date(2022, 10, 3, 8, 30),
        end: new Date(2022, 10, 3, 10, 0),
        desc: "det her er det lille mødelokale",
        locationId: 2
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Lille mødelokale",
        start: new Date(2022, 10, 4, 8, 30),
        end: new Date(2022, 10, 4, 11, 0),
        locationId: 1
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: "Mødelokale Vest",
        start: new Date(2022, 10, 5, 7, 40),
        end: new Date(2022, 10, 5, 13, 15),
        locationId: 2
    },
]


const MyCalendar = () => {


    const [newEvent, setNewEvent] = React.useState<IEvent>({ id: null, title: "", start: new Date(), end: new Date(), locationId: null });
    const [allEvents, setAllEvents] = React.useState<IEvent[]>(events);

    const handleAddEvent = () => {
        setAllEvents([...allEvents, newEvent])
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <Stack tokens={{ childrenGap: "10px" }}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={newEvent.title} onChange={(e) => setNewEvent({ ...newEvent, title: e.target.value })}
                    placeholder='Add Title'
                    style={{ width: "20%", marginRight: "10px" }} />
                <DatePicker placeholderText="Start Date" selected={newEvent.start} onChange={(start) => setNewEvent({ ...newEvent, start })} />
                <DatePicker placeholderText="End Date" selected={newEvent.start} onChange={(end) => setNewEvent({ ...newEvent, end })} />
            </Stack>
            <PrimaryButton text='Add Event' style={{ marginTop: "10px" }} onClick={handleAddEvent}/>
            <div >
                <Calendar
                    /*Error is here on the components property
                    The expected type comes from property 'toolbar' which is declared here 
                    on type 'Components<IEvent, object>'
                     */
                    components={{toolbar: CustomToolbar }}
                    defaultView='week'
                    localizer={localizer}
                    events={allEvents}
                    startAccessor="start"
                    onSelectEvent={event => alert(event.desc)}
                    endAccessor="end"
                    selectable
                    style={{ height: 1000, width: 1000, margin: "50px" }}
                    eventPropGetter={(event) => {
                        const room = meetingRooms.filter((room) => room.id === event.locationId)[0];

                        const backgroundColor = room ? room.color : "";
                        return { style: { backgroundColor: backgroundColor } }
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyCalendar
```

Again, erros I get is the following

```
index.d.ts(201, 5): The expected type comes from property 'toolbar' which is declared here on type 'Components<IEvent, object>'

index.d.ts(201, 5): The expected type comes from property 'toolbar' which is declared here on type 'Components<IEvent, object>'


No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: CalendarProps<IEvent, object> | Readonly<CalendarProps<IEvent, object>>): Calendar<IEvent, object>', gave the following error.
    Type '({ toolbar }: { toolbar: any; }) => Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<ToolbarProps<IEvent, object>>'.
      Type '({ toolbar }: { toolbar: any; }) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<ToolbarProps<IEvent, object>>'.
        Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Property 'toolbar' is missing in type 'ToolbarProps<IEvent, object> & { children?: ReactNode; }' but required in type '{ toolbar: any; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: CalendarProps<IEvent, object>, context: any): Calendar<IEvent, object>', gave the following error.
    Type '({ toolbar }: { toolbar: any; }) => Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<ToolbarProps<IEvent,
```

Any guidance would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

`const CustomToolbar = (props: any)  => { //Code }`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).